# Select works but select within union doesn't. Why?

Tags: plsql

The select statements are quite large so in a simplified presentation my issue is:

I am troubleshooting using a specific test case where only one result is returned, to test #1 alone and within a UNION'd chain of SELECT statements.

I have a SELECT statement (#1) that works (ie-returns the one test case as expected).
I have a different SELECT UNION SELECT UNION SELECT UNION SELECT statement (#2) that works for the data it is intended to return, but should return nothing with the test case.

When I add #1 to the end of #2 by adding a fifth SELECT , and look for the test case, I get no results returned.

Is there something I am missing here about how UNIONS join result sets together?  I know I'm not looking at the difference between a UNION and UNION ALL, as only one result should be found.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably delete this question, it won't be useful to anyone else.  (Although there's nothing to be ashamed of, we've all made similar mistakes.  And it's always nice to at least see someone following up and answering their own questions.)

Comment: I wanted to delete it, but they I thought to myself if someone has a similar problem and stumble across this, they will know to check that their statements are identical.   I just find that sometimes people insist on something as fact without double-checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My select statement in #2 was **not** identical to #1.